# Can the pump in a hot water recirculation system handle a large descent/ascent in the race track?

Tags: plumbing, pex

Based on the Uponor logic system, our "race track", for the hot water recirculation line, would have to shoot up (vertically) 4', over 25' (horizontally), and then down 7' and back up 7' (vertically) before returning back along the 25' length and back down the 4' drop to the water heater/recirc pump to complete the circuit.

All of the fixtures are along the first half of the race track. The 7' drop takes it to the last and furthest fixture in our home (which is an additional 4' away horizontally) which would make the furthest fixture 40' from the pump/heater). I believe the first half of the race track and the fixtures along the way are fine as far as the pressure being correct but would the portion that ascends 7' cause any issues for the pump?

I want to make sure that I'm, by design, not doing anything to put a strain on the system. I couldn't find anything that shows a portion of said track descending/ascending. I could whip the race track back around before it does the 7' drop but I'm trying to get it as close to the kitchen sink as possible since we use that the most.

Comment: The ascents and the descents balance (which is what makes a siphon work). Bends add resistance. Elevation changes don't. That said, I'm not familiar enough to understand the relationship between the pump and incoming pressure. There may be more to it than I know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comment from @isherwood is spot-on. Elevation / ascents / descents do not enter into the pump selection process at all, as long as there is no air in your pipes. (If you get air in the pipes, open a faucet to expel it.)

Select a pump that is suitable for potable water, such as stainless steel, and rated for the maximum temperature and pressure expected in your hot water loop. Flow can be quite low if your pipes are insulated.

Comment: Our pressure does not get lower than 52psi or higher than 57psi. I don't recall seeing those specs on the recirc pumps I looked at. What do you mean by "flow can be quite low if your pumps are insulated?" - I intend on insulating the entire dedicated hot circuit. Are you saying that it won't have to run as often if the pipes are insulated properly?

Comment: @LarryLupe What I mean is that if the pipes are insulated, you don't need a pump with a lot of GPM (flow rate) to keep the hot water hot within the entire loop. In the summer I can turn off the circulating pump in my house, which has a second floor, because gravity alone -- convection -- provides enough circulation to keep the pipes warm. The flow from convection, a very small flow, is enough.

Comment: @LarryLupe "I don't recall seeing those specs":  Just now I looked up a random circulating pump, a Grundfos, and it lists the spec "Max pressure 145 PSI". That's an appropriate spec for your house pressure of 52-57. Lower, say 100 PSI, would be OK too.